# navigation inside bloc flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to open a webview if i press a button in the middle of a login flow built with bloc

the current flow is managed by state

```
Page? _mapStateToPage(BuildContext context, LoginFlowState state) {
    if (state is WelcomeLoginFlowState) {
      return WelcomeScreen.page();
    } else if (state is IdLoginFlowState) {
      return IdScreen.page();
    } else if (state is LoginLoginFlowState) {
      return LoginScreen.page(options: state.options);                            
 ....
```

and in the LoginScreen there's a button that opens a webview.
problem is i kept getting an error about non existing provider.

with that in mind i changed it into a another bloc state (which looks super over engineered) and now when you press the button an even is thrown and we fall in this:

```
 } else if (state is ContactSupportFlowState) {
      return  ContactSupportScreen.page();
```

Inside the build I just dropped the webview

```
  return WebContainerScreen(
      url: UrlUtils.getWebRedirectUrl(
        tag: UrlUtils.tagSupport,
      ),
      headers: UrlUtils.getWebLinkHeader(
        acceptLanguage: AppLocalisations.of(context).locale.languageCode,
      ),
      onClosed: () {
        loginFlowBloc.add(const TryAnotherAmagIdEvent());
      },
    );
```

But again this lead into the error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer<ChangeRouteEvent>(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ChangeRouteEvent> above this Consumer<ChangeRouteEvent> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Consumer<ChangeRouteEvent> is under your MultiProvider/Provider<ChangeRouteEvent>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
```

any ideas on a possible fix?
ps. i tried this as well but same problem:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final loginFlowBloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginFlowBloc>(context);
    return Provider<LoginFlowBloc>.value(
      value: loginFlowBloc,
    builder: (context, child) {
    return WebContainerScreen(
      url: UrlUtils.getWebRedirectUrl(
        tag: UrlUtils.tagAmagSupport,
      ),
      headers: UrlUtils.getWebLinkHeader(
        acceptLanguage: AppLocalisations.of(context).locale.languageCode,
      ),
      onClosed: () {
        loginFlowBloc.add(const TryAnotherAmagIdEvent());
      },
    );
    }
    );
  }
```

Comment: How is build the widget calling ChangeRouteEvent? It's missing a BlocProvider above it I thinks.

Comment: I tried with Provider (see edit) and with BlocProvider

Comment: Why using a variable of BlocProvider and use it with Provider? Why not using using directly BlocProvider.of<LoginFlowBloc> ?

Comment: like i said, i tried with both blocprovider and provider, same error

Comment: And where is used ChangeRouteEvent ? The bloc linked to this event isn't provided in your example.

Comment: my bad, that's part of the webview

https://pastebin.com/ZAfAFdBL

Comment: with this code, the consumer doesn't create the provider for ChangeRouteEvent and there is no provider above it, right?

Comment: mhh I think yes you're right

Comment: Can you try to set a Provider<ChangeRouteEvent> in top of your webview?

Comment: i fixed it using a slide transition instead thank you